# Modify websocket status code in $connect, $disconnect or any custom route of API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I want to modify the event code and event reason of the websocket with custom codes.

I want to use below reserved codes for application

```
4000-4999

    Status codes in the range 4000-4999 are reserved for private use
    and thus can't be registered. Such codes can be used by prior
    agreements between WebSocket applications. The interpretation of
    these codes is undefined by this protocol.
```

Is there a way to achieve the same?

Right now I am getting below event code when I close the websocket from javascript client using `socket.close()`

```
event.code=1005 event.reason=
```

Is there a way to modify this on the API gateway lambda side?

I tried below in disconnect lambda

```
exports.handler =  async function(event, context, callback) {
  var res ={
        "statusCode": 4090,
        "body": "Connection closed"
    };
  callback(null, res);
}
```

does not work. I am using Lambda proxy integration on API gateway/

Answer (score 0):

The disconnect lambda is called when a client disconnects. You want to use the connection management API to disconnect a client. Codes don't seem to be supported but you can close the connection.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-how-to-call-websocket-api-connections.html

Do be careful as building the callbackUrl from the event seems to not work properly when using a custom domain and you'll want to get the url from the stage itself.